# Bash: Error logging to a file, but with a line length restriction

Tags: bash

I'm currently using this command `./myprogram 2> error.log` to log the program errors to a specific file. However, some lines are so long that I have to scroll continuously to read through them. I would like to error log with a set line length limit (e.g 80 characters per line), where lines that go over the limit continue on the next line, etc.

Raw Contents:

```
This line is not over 80 characters.
This line is over 80 characters thus will be cut at the 80th character, and will continue onto the next line.
```

Error Log (Final Result):

```
This line is not over 80 characters.
This line is over 80 characters thus will be cut at the 80th character, and will
 continue onto the next line.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what tool do you use to read the lines that doesn't fold for you automatically? I can't think of a tool that would make you scroll, what are you using?

Comment: @terdon, could be `less -S` or `journalctl` (which calls `less` with `-FRSXMK` by default via the `$LESS` envvar) or `vi` with `nowrap` on.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the output of your program to `fold` to wrap the output at a width of 80 characters then redirecting that to a file:

```
./myprogram 2>&1 >/dev/null | fold -w 80 > error.log
```

The above assumes you only care about keeping stderr.